# Make one query or other if var equal to

Tags: mysql, database

I have a couple of weeks stuck in this problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I have a lineage model for my navigation header like this:

```
id     name      parent_id     is_post      post_feed
-------------------------------------------------------
1      contact       0           0           "<a>..."
2      about         1           1           "<p>..."
3      who we are    1           1           "<h1>..."
4      where we are  1           1           "<h2>..."
```

And I get the current post processing the last one:

```
www.website.com/contact/about
```

In this case would be "about"

The problem is:
If the user click into "contact" that contains -> about, who we are, where we are... I'd like to show the sons of this "category" or "post" because its row says that has no post

```
    id     name      parent_id     is_post      post_feed
-------------------------------------------------------
   1      contact       0           0           "<a>..."
```

So I was thinking (in my ignorance) to make one query or other if is_post = 0 but It doesn't work

```
SET @id = 1;
SET @is_post = (SELECT is_post FROM posts WHERE id = @id);
SELECT (IF (@is_post = 0, (id, name), (id, post_feed)))
FROM posts
```

Any suggestion to solved it?

Thanks a lot, friends!

Comment: Can you make different queries moving the conditional logic to `PHP`, instead of overcomplicating your `SQL`?

Comment: Hi lucke84! I've thinking about too but... I'd have o make 2 querys for that.
1. for search is_post = 0? them.
2. make a query or other.

Comment: You're doing two queries anyways.

Comment: I mean one query... process the result in php... make another query...
But I'm thinkin' that you're right that can I list * in the same mysqli_fetch_array and take that is not equal to is_post = 0... If I can't do this in mysql, I'll try your way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try union all:

```
SELECT id, name
  FROM posts
  WHERE @is_post = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT id, post_feed
  FROM posts
  WHERE @is_post <> 0
```

Comment: Hi Kordirko!
I've recieved this error: #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Do you know why? thanks!